# Does anybody know a function to avoid point labels to overlap in R?

Tags: r, plotrix

Ternary diagram
[image]
*Hello. Does anybody know how to use thigmophobe.labels from PLOTRIX? or any other function that voids the point labels to overlap? I am trying to make a ternary diagram with sediment data, but I got this problem and I have no idea how to solve it. Some point labels are overlapping. Maybe it's simple, but I a new R user...*

That's an example of the code.

```
library ('rysgran')
data (camargo2001)

class.percent (camargo2001, mode="total")
percent <- class.percent(camargo2001, mode="total")
x<-percent[2:4]
rysgran.ternary(x, method = "pejrup", lang = "e", main="",
                show.labels=FALSE, label.points=TRUE, axis.labels = NULL, show.names = TRUE,
                cex.labels= 1, cex.points=0.9, show.legend=FALSE,
                cex.axis=1, cex.names = 0.8, col.names = "blue", col = "blue",
                col.labels= "black", col.axis= "black", col.lines= "black",
                pch = 16, lty.grid = 10, pos=3)
```

Comment: `ggternary` (or whatever it's called) + `ggrepel` packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be difficult because the points are so clustered in the lower left corner. Also helper functions such as `thigamaphobe.labels` in `plotrix` (and the other functions mentioned on the manual page for the function) need to know the coordinates of the point, but `rysgran.ternary` does not return that information. Some of the other ternary plot functions do or provide a function to convert the 3d coordinates to 2d plot coordinates.

Given that, you may be able to get by with some of the following approaches:

1. If you are plotting to a print device, make the plot bigger so that the overlaps are not as severe. When I recreate your plot and drag the window larger, many of the overlaps disappear.
2. Change `cex.labels=` to something smaller, e.g. .8. That will make the labels smaller.
3. Reposition the labels with `pos=c(3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3)`. That tells R where to plot the label relative to the point, 1-below, 2-left, 3-above, 4-right. Currently you are plotting all labels using 3, above the point.
4. More work, but more control. Do not plot the labels automatically. Generate the plot and then use `pt <- locator()` and click on the points on the graph to get their plot coordinates. Use this information with `points()` to plot the labels exactly where you want them. Save the coordinates so whenever you regenerate the plot, you have the coordinates already computed.

Comment: Wow thank you very much. You saved my day. Approach number 3 actually worked.